# CKEditor is modifying my HTML source - and not for the better. Any way to prevent this?

Tags: ckeditor

I realize there are many questions about CKEditor modifying HTML source. But none of the suggestions appear to work.

In particular, the most general suggested change:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

seems to help quite a bit, but a lot still gets changed.

For example, the following HTML entered in SOURCE mode gets modified.

Original:

```
<p><a name="top"></p>
<p>Over the course of its 2 phases the ACCRA programme has co-authored and published a large collection of reports, case studies, evaluations and working papers. These are all available to download for free here.<br>
Our resources are categorised as follows: <a href="#top">General Programme Information</a> | <a href="#research_reports ">Research reports</a> | <a href="#case_studies">Country case studies</a> | <a href="#Phase 1 Evaluation ">Phase 1 Evaluation</a> | <a href="#Working_papers">Working papers</a>| <a href="#Publications in Portuguese">Publications in Portuguese</a></p>
```

Turns into this:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<p><a name="top"></a></p>
<p><a name="top"> </a></p>
<p><a name="top">Over the course of its 2 phases the ACCRA programme has co-authored and published a large collection of reports, case studies, evaluations and working papers. These are all available to download for free here.<br>
Our resources are categorised as follows: </a><a href="#top">General Programme Information</a> | <a href="#research_reports ">Research reports</a> | <a href="#case_studies">Country case studies</a> | <a href="#Phase 1 Evaluation ">Phase 1 Evaluation</a> | <a href="#Working_papers">Working papers</a>| <a href="#Publications in Portuguese">Publications in Portuguese</a></p>
```

Duplicated lines and even spaces are added.

Another example:

Original:

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div style="clear: both">&nbsp;</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I could go on, but you get the point.

The changed source gets rendered differently from the original. For example, rows of publications which were nicely aligned get slightly misaligned if opened and then saved in the CKEditor.

Is there a way of telling CKEditor to please leave my valid HTML source as is?

Comment: please note that `<p><a name="top"></p>` is not a valid HTML ocde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `config.allowedContent = true;` should do the trick for leaving your VALID html code intact.

But in the case that there is no valid html code it will try to correct it in order to show it correctly (that is because CKEditor is not a code writing tool but a WYSIWYG tool).

In your first example your html is not valid (`<p><a name="top"></p>`). The `<a>` tag should have a corresponding `</a>` end tag.

In your second example you can disable the automatic fillup of empty tags with the `&nbsp;` using the option:

```
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

Comment: Thank you. Both your answers (fixing the invalid anchor tag and the config.fillEmptyBlocks = false; setting) completely solved the current issue I was experiencing. I can now go into the CKeditor, go into source, see the source exactly as entered, and when I save there are no changes and everything stays nicely aligned as it should be. So thanks very much for helping me solve this long-standing confusion!